PHP Notice WP_Scripts::localize was called incorrectly in WordPress
I got this (PHP Notice: WP_Scripts::localize was called incorrectly) on one of my wordpress website. It is due to one of my old wordpress catalog plugin, which is no longer updated by the author, and when I turn off that plugin the php notice will be gone.
I realize that it is due to the incorrect use of wp_localize_script by this plugin so I found the keyword wp_localize_script in all plugin files and found that code in 2 places of a 1 file of plugin.
    wp_localize_script('catalog-all-js', 'catalog_disable_right_click', get_option('product_catalog_disable_right_click'));

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'id' => 'no origin_code catalog',

    ), $atts));

    return origincode_products_list($atts['id']);

}
add_shortcode('origin_code_catalog', 'origincode_products_list_shotrcode');

and this
wp_localize_script('catalog-all-js', 'catalog_disable_right_click', get_option('product_catalog_disable_right_click'));

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'id' => 'no origin_code catalog',

    ), $atts));

    return origin_code_catalog_single_product($atts['id']);

}
add_shortcode('origin_code_catalog_single_product', 'origin_code_catalog_single_product_shotrcode');

my hosting is using php7.4 with WP 6.6.1, Any fix for the above issue will be appreciated...

It's because this: get_option('product_catalog_disable_right_click') is probably not an array (most likely a bool), which is what the wp_localize_script is expecting. Try changing that line to [ 'product_catalog_disable_right_click' => get_option('product_catalog_disable_right_click')]

Localization work before the shortcode registration. Here is the use of localization.
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function(){
  wp_localize_script('catalog-all-js', 'catalog_disable_right_click', get_option('product_catalog_disable_right_click'));
});

